# Getting Dynamics CRM Metadata

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 On Premise, I'm trying to get some specific metadata, basically get through SQL Server the field physical name, display name(Label) and the field value from a given entity. This is the query I have so far:

```
 select  a.PhysicalName, I.Label
 from  [dbo].[Attribute] a
 inner join [dbo].[Entity] e on e.EntityId=a.EntityId
 inner join [dbo].[LocalizedLabel] l on l.ObjectId = a.AttributeId
 where e.Name='DesiredEntityName'
```

With this query I can get the fields and displayed label from the given entity, however I don't see the way on how to join and get the list of values for each field.

Comment: Are you looking for optionset aka picklist values? Then look at stringmap table.

Comment: I need all fields (physical names) from a specified entity (table) plus displayed names (Labels) and their values, not optionset vales.

Answer (score 1):

You have to query from `stringmap` table where all the picklist (optionset) values will be stored.

```
SELECT AttributeValue as Value, Value as Label
FROM StringMap s
JOIN EntityLogicalView e on s.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode
WHERE AttributeName = 'DesiredAttributeName'
AND e.Name = 'DesiredEntityName'
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```

[Retrieve Option Set Metadata Via SQL](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/crmmemories/archive/2017/05/02/retrieve-option-set-metadata-via-sql)

**Edit:**

I see what you want now. You basically need to mimic what Product is doing when you export the data to Excel.

When you do the below query using database table or view or filtered view, you want the display name as ALIAS.

```
SELECT name AS [Account Name], telephone1 AS [Business Phone]  from Account
```

The problem would be that **Schema Name** `telephone1` is readily available in table where Account records data is stored, whereas **Display Name** `Business Phone` is stored in multiple different tables like **Entity, Attribute, LocalizedLabel**.

You may have to do your own view or query concatenation to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you Arun but I don't need optionset values, I know how to retrieves them, what I need is all fields (physical names) from a specified entity (table) plus displayed names (Labels) and their values

Comment: @Poyson1 metadata is different & values storing tables are different. If you want account there will be filteredaccount view with crm security model imposed and account table. The fields metadata will be stored in attribute table, data is stored in corresponding account table

Comment: What about a Pivot with Attribute bale (field names) with corresponding desired table, I know it can be possible but the issue would be how to make them the same order as all fields should be sorted in same order. I don't know if you following me in this idea...

Comment: @Poyson1 what I believe you want is, export the data from crm entity in Advanced find in excel & do slicing dicing in pivot table. When you do from sql only schema name will come, you just want to pull display label instead. Is that your problem?

Comment: I dont wanna do that through advanced find, duplicated displayed names (label) raised and error, that why I want to create the query directly from the DB by selecting all fields from the desired entity and add some how the Label of each field. I'm trying using Pivot/Unpivot. If you have a similar solution please post it here. Thank you.